# Taking vacation last minute- boss not there

Tags: professionalism, vacation

My boss is basically everyone in the office as I just help everyone out- however I go to the receptionist who is mostly my boss to take days off, and I tell my two coworkers/ bosses who I work with most. The office can survive without me- I'm not overly important. I just found out from my mom (annoyingly so late) that next week is the week we are going to Canada. That is 8 days away. The receptionist/mostly my boss is away for the entire week- so she won't find out I took the week off until the day I'm already in Canada. I don't know who to talk to, what they will say, or how the receptionist will feel. please help!

Comment: Talk to your boss's boss, if there is one.

Comment: Does the receptionist respond to email while she is away? Does someone in the office have a number she can be reached at?

Comment: Be prepared to get your request for leave denied.  Some jobs would not be ok with 1 week notice about a week-long vacation.

Answer (score 9):

> I don't know who to talk to, what they will say, or how the
>   receptionist will feel. please help!

Certainly there is someone who fills in for the receptionist when she is away. Or she must have left a phone number or email address where she can be reached.

At least she must have a boss, right?

If you don't know who fills in or how to contact her, go to the receptionist's boss, and explain your situation.